# can't modify the parameter value in function. (edit button not working)

Tags: javascript, html

(attached js fiddle below) I am able to access the value of `expN` `expD` `expA` `expT` but not able to set the new values for them, after clicking on edit button I am getting the vlaues of siblings of edit button but can't set them to new value for input fields (`expN` `expD` `expA` `expT`).

```
expBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const expN = expName.value;
  const expD = expDate.value;
  const expA = expAmount.value;
  const expT = expType.value;

  if (expT === "choose-type") {
    alert("Please choose the expense type !");
    return;
  }

  const tr = document.createElement("tr");

  // Serial No
  const td1 = document.createElement("td");
  const td1Text = document.createTextNode(tableChild.length - 1);
  td1.appendChild(td1Text);
  tr.appendChild(td1);

  // Expresnse Type
  const td2 = document.createElement("td");
  const td2Text = document.createTextNode(expT);
  td2.appendChild(td2Text);
  td2.classList.add("expT-data");
  tr.appendChild(td2);

  // Expense Name
  const td3 = document.createElement("td");
  const td3Text = document.createTextNode(expN);
  td3.appendChild(td3Text);
  td3.classList.add("expN-data");
  tr.appendChild(td3);

  // Expense Date
  const td4 = document.createElement("td");
  const td4Text = document.createTextNode(expD);
  td4.appendChild(td4Text);
  td4.classList.add("expD-data");
  tr.appendChild(td4);

  // Expense Amount
  const td5 = document.createElement("td");
  const td5Text = document.createTextNode(expA + " Rs");
  td5.appendChild(td5Text);
  td5.classList.add("expA-data");
  tr.appendChild(td5);

  // Delete Btn
  const td6 = document.createElement("td");
  const td6Text = document.createTextNode("Delete");
  td6.append(td6Text);
  td6.classList.add("del-btn");
  tr.appendChild(td6);

  const td7 = document.createElement("td");
  const td7Text = document.createTextNode("Edit");
  td7.append(td7Text);
  td7.classList.add("edit-btn");
  tr.appendChild(td7);

  table.appendChild(tr);

  const editBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("edit-btn");
  editFun(editBtn, expN, expD, expA, expT);

  const delBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("del-btn");
  btnFun(delBtn);
});

// Function for Delete Button
function btnFun(delBtn) {
  Array.from(delBtn).forEach((e) => {
    e.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      const a = e.currentTarget;
      a.parentElement.remove();
    });
  });
}
```

Edit Button

```
function editFun(editBtn, expN, expD, expA, expT) {
  Array.from(editBtn).forEach((e) => {
    e.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      const siblings = e.currentTarget.parentElement.childNodes;

      expT = siblings[1].innerText;
      expN = siblings[2].innerText;
      expD = siblings[3].innerText;
      expA = siblings[4].innerText;

      
    });
  });
}
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gqbmfkus/6/)

Comment: could you please be more specific , what are you trying to achieve

Comment: @FaizalHussain I would request you to visit the js fiddle first and try the edit button.

Comment: are you trying to fill the inputs with , values from the table row ?

Comment: @FaizalHussain yes

Answer (score 0):

you should be sending the refernce of the element rather than the value , please check this working example

```
const expAmount = document.getElementById("exp-amount");
const expName = document.getElementById("exp-name");
const expDate = document.getElementById("exp-date");
const expBtn = document.getElementById("exp-btn");
const expType = document.getElementById("exp-type");
const table = document.getElementById("table");
const tableChild = document.getElementById("table").childNodes;

expBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const expN = expName;
  const expD = expDate;
  const expA = expAmount;
  const expT = expType;

  if (expT === "choose-type") {
    alert("Please choose the expense type !");
    return;
  }

  const tr = document.createElement("tr");

  // Serial No
  const td1 = document.createElement("td");
  const td1Text = document.createTextNode(tableChild.length - 1);
  td1.appendChild(td1Text);
  tr.appendChild(td1);

  // Expresnse Type
  const td2 = document.createElement("td");
  const td2Text = document.createTextNode(expT.value);
  td2.appendChild(td2Text);
  td2.classList.add("expT-data");
  tr.appendChild(td2);

  // Expense Name
  const td3 = document.createElement("td");
  const td3Text = document.createTextNode(expN.value);
  td3.appendChild(td3Text);
  td3.classList.add("expN-data");
  tr.appendChild(td3);

  // Expense Date
  const td4 = document.createElement("td");
  const td4Text = document.createTextNode(expD.value);
  td4.appendChild(td4Text);
  td4.classList.add("expD-data");
  tr.appendChild(td4);

  // Expense Amount
  const td5 = document.createElement("td");
  const td5Text = document.createTextNode(expA.value + " Rs");
  td5.appendChild(td5Text);
  td5.classList.add("expA-data");
  tr.appendChild(td5);

  // Delete Btn
  const td6 = document.createElement("td");
  const td6Text = document.createTextNode("Delete");
  td6.append(td6Text);
  td6.classList.add("del-btn");
  tr.appendChild(td6);

  const td7 = document.createElement("td");
  const td7Text = document.createTextNode("Edit");
  td7.append(td7Text);
  td7.classList.add("edit-btn");
  tr.appendChild(td7);

  table.appendChild(tr);

  const editBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("edit-btn");
  editFun(editBtn, expN, expD, expA, expT);

  const delBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("del-btn");
  btnFun(delBtn);
});

// Function for Delete Button
function btnFun(delBtn) {
  Array.from(delBtn).forEach((e) => {
    e.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      const a = e.currentTarget;
      a.parentElement.remove();
    });
  });
}

// Function for Edit Button
function editFun(editBtn, expN, expD, expA, expT) {
  Array.from(editBtn).forEach((e) => {
    e.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      const siblings = e.currentTarget.parentElement.childNodes;

      expT.value = siblings[1].innerText;
      expN.value = siblings[2].innerText;
      expD.value = siblings[3].innerText;
      expA.value = siblings[4].innerText.split(" Rs")[0];

      console.log(expA ,  siblings[4].innerText);
    });
  });
}
```